# Recasting NumPy array slice with astype

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

The code

```
a = 100. * np.random.randn(200)                                                                        
a = a.astype(int)
```

recasts `a` as an array of integer numbers. Meanwhile, the code

```
a = 100. * np.random.randn(200)                                                                        
a[:] = a.astype(int)
```

recasts `a` as an array of integer *floats* obtained by truncating the original values of `a`. Why doesn't the second case also give integers?

I'm currently using Python 3.8 and NumPy 1.23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, `a.astype(int)` return a new array with `dtype('int32')`.

- Line `a = a.astype(int)` alters array `a` with the new array return by `astype(int)`.
- Meanwhile, `a[:] = a.astype(int)` only update the values of the `a` array, not the dtype.